# method map in interface java.util.stream.Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-stream, apache-commons-dbutils

The code listing:

```
protected List<R> getRows(String startDate, String endDate, Function<MapListHandler, R> func){

    ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
    List<R> rows = null;
    try(Connection c = cm.getConnection()) {

        String sql = getSql();

        rows = new QueryRunner()
                .query(c, sql, new MapListHandler(), startDate, endDate, startDate, endDate)
                .stream()
                .map(func).collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        cm.closeConnection();
    }

    return rows;
}
```

fails to compile with the following message:

> method map in interface java.util.stream.Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
>   [ERROR] required: java.util.function.Function<? super java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>,? extends R>
>   [ERROR] found: java.util.function.Function<org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapListHandler,R>
>   [ERROR] reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
>   [ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.util.function.Function<org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapListHandler,R> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>,? extends R>)

Comment: The code compiles if I use with Map<String, Object>  instead of MapHanlder

Comment: Sure, it compiles with `Function<Map<String, Object>, R> func` because `Map<String, Object>` is the type of the Stream elements. What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

A [`MapListHandler`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/handlers/MapListHandler.html) will cause query to return a `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

This means that `stream()` will return a `Stream<Map<String, Object>>`. Its `map()` method thus expects a `Function<? super Map<String, Object>, ? extends R>`.

Of course a `MapListHandler` is not a super type of `Map<String, Object>` so `func` is not a valid parameter for `map()`.